# Getting 404 Error when deploying firebase web app

Tags: node.js, firebase, deployment, http-status-code-404, endpoint

Hi when I deploy my firebase web app, I get a 404 not found error when hitting endpoints.

Here is part of my index.js file found in my src/routes/functions folder.

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 80;
server.listen(port,'127.0.0.1');
console.debug('Server listening on port ' + port);

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "*",
  authDomain: "*",
  databaseURL: "*",
  projectId: "*",
  storageBucket: "*",
  messagingSenderId: "93371481008",
  appId: "*",
  measurementId: "G-NR8N5HP6RZ"
};
// Initialize Firebase
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}else {
  firebase.app(); // if already initialized, use that one
}
router.get('/test', function(req,res){
  console.log("router map test");
  res.send("test page");
});
```

When I deploy the firebase web app by typeing:
`sudo firebase deploy`

When I try and hit the test endpoint in index.js - `curl -X GET https://PROJECT_ID/test` I get a 404 error.

Here is my firebase.json file:

````
  "hosting": {
    "public": "src/main/www",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },```
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "src/routes/functions",
      "codebase": "map-print",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/test",
      "function": "test"
    }
  ]
}
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing to export the function itself.

I suppose you're using [`express`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) to handle your routes, so here's a minimal example:

```
import express from 'express'

const app = express()
app.get('/test', req, res => {
  return res.send('hello world')
})

// this is what you're missing
exports.myFuncionName = functions.https.onRequest( app )
```

Comment: Thanks, ```exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);``` worked for me. The firebase app URL was ```https://us-central1-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/app```

Comment: Glad I help you. Please don’t forget to mark my answer as the sollution to your question 